What should I make of this spectrum analyzer data?
Here I have two signals that I placed into a spectrum analyzer. Channel 1 (yellow) comes from an avalanche photodiode + TIA circuit that has a 50 Ω output resistor, which is directly connected via BNC to the SA. Channel 3 (blue) is just a short circuit. The signals I get and their FFTs are below.

The primary noise from my circuit should be Johnson noise from a resistor and noise from my photodiode, which should be on the order of 1 uV/sqrt Hz. This is probably much greater than the noise from the short circuit, but it seems like the two FFTs are showing that the signals have the same noise floor. Also, my circuit has a bandwidth of about 10^7 Hz and I'm not detecting a decline in the noise at that level either, so I'm pretty sure I'm not detecting the actual noise in my circuit here. Any tips?
The SA I'm using is the Infiniium DSA90604A. For reference my circuit design is below.

EDIT:
I zoomed out on the voltage readings to capture a longer exposure time. I also adjusted the range on the FFT so I can see now that the yellow is indeed above the green (I swapped this from the blue input).
The noise rolls off at a point of around 50 MHz. I used a spice simulation that showed that the bandwidth of the circuit (because of the low pass filter) is on the order of at most 10 MHz. Does this measurement indicate my bandwidth is actually much higher? The first picture below is the FFT relative to a short circuit on the green input, and the second is relative to no connection on the green input.



Test the spectrum with some signal on the detector so that you can see the shot noise.

Can you post an oscilloscope screenshot?

Your frequency domain scales are set to 100dB per division and 2 GHz per division on both channels.  Change these scales to something much smaller to see anything meaningful.
a starting point could be to set the frequency scale to 1Mhz/div and amplitude to 10dB/div.

Thanks for the tip! I've edited my original post, but am now wondering whether I can use the FFT as a reliable estimate for the bandwidth of my circuit. Please let me know if you have any advice on that.

Measuring noise accurately is tricky  business.  You can easily be fooled by noise coupling into your measurement setup, which could be the case here.
I don’t know that using an FFT will give you the best possible results either due to quantization  and rounding etc.  You would likely have better results with a spectrum analyzer.

Like you've done, it's good practice to compare a measurement of ground to the measurement of signal noise to see how much of the noise is from the measurement setup.   My interpretation of the data presented so far is that your measurement probing setup is picking up just as much if not more environmental noise as the real noise output from the circuit.  I'd focus on improving your measurement setup, are you using shielded probe leads with minimal ground wire length? Move any computers or other electronics farther from measurement setup and device under test. Also try measuring the power supply into the circuit under test, does circuit power look just as noisy?  Consider sending a photo of your probes and measurement wiring.
